# 403 Forbidden when Deploying asp.net 4.0 site to IIS 7

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, asp.net

So I have an EC2 instance running, the URL
NoWeatherSurprises.com
I have the DNS pointing there, and I set up a new site in IIS 7 and pointed it to a folder.  I used Visual Studios Web Developer 2010 express to publish to this folder.  It now has the binaries and such.

However if I go to NoWeatherSurprises.com I get the welcome to IIS 7 screen.
I'd expect to go to my application
If I navigate to http://noweathersurprises.com/weather/ [weather was the folder I published to under wwwroot]
I get a 403 forbidden.  I have no idea why, I am guessing that it is trying to do a directory listing or something instead of launching my MVC Application.

So 2 problems in summary.

1. It is not pointing the domain to the folder directly and I need to add /weather
2. I am getting a 403 forbidden instead of the results of my home controller with the index action.

I am new to IIS 7, I had been using IIS 6 and had a lot less trouble setting it up, but I suspect that's my own fault and i am just missing something.
Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Have you [added a hostname binding](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx) for the hostname? IIS needs that to figure out what site should serve a particular request. Alternatively, you should set the site in question as the default site (instead of the automatically created default one).